# Having trouble displaying correct max value when user types (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var numbers = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
        var min = numbers.Min();
        var max = numbers.Max();
        textBox2.Text = string.Format("min: {0} max: {1}", min, max);
        {

        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }    
}
```

Having trouble displaying correct max value when user types (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10)
I am new to programming and I am a little confused on what to change my max {0} to in order to get ten to display as 10 and not 9. I was wondering if anybody can help

Comment: `Split()` gives you an array of `string`s.  You'll want to convert those into `int`s if you want to get the maximum number they entered.  As you have it coded it is giving you the last string alphabetically, which is 9.

Comment: the spit is still strings or chars, so "10" is < "9" you'll have to convert them to an array of numbers first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var numbers = textBox1.Text.Split(' ')
.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
var min = numbers.Min();
var max = numbers.Max();
```

Add a second textbox to your form and add this line below everything.

```
textbox2.Text = string.Format("min: {0} max: {1}", min, max);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an array of strings, so when you use `Min` and `Max` on that, the values will be compared as strings.

While as numbers `10 > 9`, as strings `"10" < "9"`, because as strings they would be sorted as `"0", "1", "10", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"`.

You can split the string, then convert each string to a number:

```
int[] numbers =
  textBox1.Text.Split(' ')
  .Select(s => Int32.Parse(s))
  .ToArray();
```

Now you can use `Min` and `Max` on the values, and they will be compared as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The values you are extracting from `var numbers = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');` will be an array of strings not numbers. You will need to parse the entries in your `numbers` array to turn them from strings to numbers. The "max" string in your sequence is, in fact, 9, not 10. because 9 sorts higher than 1.

```
string textBox1 = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10";
var numbersAsStrings = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');

List<double> numbersAsDoubles = new List<double>();

foreach (var numberAsString in numbersAsStrings)
{
    double numberAsDouble;
    if (double.TryParse(numberAsString,out numberAsDouble))
    {
        numbersAsDoubles.Add(numberAsDouble);
    }
}

var min = numbersAsDoubles.Min();
var max = numbersAsDoubles.Max();
var outputMessage =  string.Format("min: {0} max: {1}", min, max);
textBox2.Text = outputMessage;
```

The advantage to this method is that it uses `TryParse`. If you only use `Parse` and a use types something that is not a number or a space a `System.FormatException` will be thrown. You can see this if you try to run this code

```
string textBox1 = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 A";
var numbers = textBox1.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

The same error will occur if your user types `10.1` because you are using `int.Parse` instead out `double.Parse` but maybe that is what you want.

Comment: The only issue is the user inputs the numbers

Comment: That's fine. I made testBox1 a variable but it is not a local variable in your code, it is a textbox object. You can use it as such.